# React axios response -> Authorization value does not appear in the header

Tags: reactjs, axios

It's my Api Code.
There is no Authorization in the response header, but if you look at the header in the Network window, it exists.
I would appreciate it if you could help me figure out what the problem is and how to solve it.

```
const onLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    var encrypt = new JSEncrypt();
    encrypt.setPublicKey(REACT_APP_ENC_PUB_KEY);
    let encryptedPassword = encrypt.encrypt(password);
    try {
        let res = await axios.post(
            `http://xx.xx/api/v1/users/login`,
            {
                id: email,
                password: encryptedPassword,
            },
            {
                headers: {
                    Accept: 'application/json',
                    'Content-type': 'Application/json',
                    withCredentials : true
                },
            },
        )}; 
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        let errmsg = err.response.data.message;
        setErrMsg(errmsg);
    }
};
```

[console axios response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ya5C.png)
[Network axios response header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpZYS.png)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: I try this code, but problem is same... 

```
headers: {
 Accept: 'application/json',
 'Content-type': 'Application/json',
 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Authorization',
},
```

Comment: You can't set that header on the _client_ - it would be completely pointless if you could. It's a _response_ header, the server needs to set it.